# LINUX KERNEL: eth_hdr function returning invalid h_proto field

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have built and running into the latest linux kernel(Checked out from github on Aug 12th 2017).

I have REALTEK ethernet network device in my laptop.

I have isolated open source realtek driver code and placed some debug prints.
Then, I compiled driver against current running linux and loaded it successfully.

My changes are:
    1. DUMP PACKET in RX POLL METHOD.

In RX POLL method, packet is copied from RX queue to SKB.
Just before invoking,
    napi_receive_skb(skb) I have done the following.

---

```
printk(KERN_INFO "NAPI RECEIVE SKB -----PROTOCOL :0x%x\n", skb->protocol);
struct ethhdr *l2 = eth_hdr(skb);
u8 *p = (u8 *)l2;
printk(KERN_INFO "ETHHDR :%2x %2x %2x %2x %2x %2x",
                  p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5]);
p += 6;
printk(KERN_INFO "ETHHDR :%2x %2x %2x %2x %2x %2x",
                 p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[5]);
p += 2;
printk(KERN_INFO "ETHHDR :%2x %2x", p[0], p[1]);

napi_gro_receive(&tp->napi, skb);
u64_stats_update_begin(&tp->rx_stats.syncp);
```

---

```
Actual OutPUT In dmesg:

Aug 23 12:40:49 vkalyanam-Lenovo-B41-80 kernel: [ 5246.684694] NAPI RECEIVE SKB -----PROTOCOL :0x8
Aug 23 12:40:49 vkalyanam-Lenovo-B41-80 kernel: [ 5246.684703] ETHHDR :1c 39 47 ae 3d 65
Aug 23 12:40:49 vkalyanam-Lenovo-B41-80 kernel: [ 5246.684709] ETHHDR :f4 8e 38 a4 5e 9f
Aug 23 12:40:49 vkalyanam-Lenovo-B41-80 kernel: [ 5246.684715] ETHHDR :38 a4

    struct ethhdr {
        unsigned char   h_dest[ETH_ALEN];   /* destination eth addr */
        unsigned char   h_source[ETH_ALEN]; /* source ether addr    */
        __be16      h_proto;        /* packet type ID field */
    } __attribute__((packed));
```

Why h_proto filed is showing wrong.??
Aug 23 12:40:49 vkalyanam-Lenovo-B41-80 kernel: [ 5246.684715] ETHHDR :38 a4

For every packet, I do see the same value "38 a4".

Comment: I missed one more update. Adding that info here.
skb->protocol is printing valide value.
I do see that have shown 0800 for TCP Packets.

skb->protocol = eth_type_trans(skb, dev);
Above is the code where SKB protocol is updating.

Though, eth_hdr kernel should give valid value.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the issue in your code is that you do *p += 2;* after you read the second address. You might need *p += 6;* instead.

Indeed, skipping just 2 bytes shows you the two "wrong" bytes from the second address: f4 8e **38 a4** 5e 9f.